# Mongo $sample (aggregation) not working inside GEToperation in a node REST server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I´m implementing a REST server with node with MongoDB as persistence database.

I would like to implement a GET operation that returns a random document in a collection, but when I implement the $sample (aggregation) method, It work as if I was implementing a find({}) returning all documents.

this is the code i´m using in my server.js file

```
app.get("/api/contacts", function(req, res) {

  //GET: find a random contact
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).aggregate(
   { $sample: { size: 1 } }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get contacts.");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(docs);     
    }
  });

});
```

the require part of the server.js file is this:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;

var CONTACTS_COLLECTION = "contacts";

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The versions that I'm using are :

- O.S. Windows 8.1
- node v6.11.0
- express 3.10.10
- mongodb 3.2.13 (cloud db from mlab)

**Additional info** : If try to connect to the database with the Mongobooster client and run :

```
db.contacts.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
)
```

It works OK finding and returning a random document, but in the REST operation it isn't working well, so is there any additional restriction in this case ?

Comment: Shouldn't the aggregate function take an array? So: db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 }}])

Comment: Thank you @benjiman , that was the mistake, and now is working well. Please put your comment as an answer so I' can rate you as the solution.

Comment: Your welcome. I just posted my answer. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate takes an array of arguments as it's input. You forgot to put your `$sample` command into an array:

```
db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 }}]).toArray();
```